# Overload a function so that it can convert a base class to a derived class as a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I am attempting to model a 3D world, which has objects of spheres and capsules inside of it. I modeled it in a way that the shape class is the base class and that the sphere and capsule classes inherit from the base class (which, if I implemented it correctly, is a perfectly virtual class).

```
class Shape
{

protected:
    COLORREF color;

public:
    virtual COLORREF getColor() =0;


};


    class Capsule: public Shape
{

private:
    Point start;
    Direction direction;
    int dist, r;
    //Color color;
    //COLORREF color;

public:

    Capsule(Point start, Direction direction, int inputdist, int inputr, COLORREF inputcolor);

    COLORREF getColor();

};

    class Sphere : public Shape
{

private:
    int r;
    Point p;
    //Color color;
    //COLORREF color;

public:
    Sphere(int x, int y, int z , int r, COLORREF inputcolor) ;
    COLORREF getColor();
    Point getpoint();
    int getradius();
};
```

Then I have a function in a different class that takes in either a pointer to a Sphere object or a pointer to a Capsule object.

```
bool Collideswith(Sphere *s);
bool Collideswith(Capsule *c);
```

But I would like to force one of the above functions to be called when i call

```
Shape *myshape = new Sphere(0,0,0,4, RGB(0,0,0));
 if(myRay.Collideswith(myshape)) { blah... }
```

But the issue is that since Collideswith only takes in pointers to Capsules or pointers to spheres, when I call it right now it won't take in this pointer to what I'm passing in, which is a pointer to a shape.

I can't change the fact that I'm passing in a shape pointer, but I need to figure out how to have the Collideswith() function take the shape pointer. (Maybe by creating a overloaded function that takes the shape pointer and can figure out if the shape is a capsule or a sphere somehow?)

Any suggestions will be really appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you change the code of the other class that has the Collideswith() method? Or should I assume that you can only modify the Shape-related classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a virtual method in your `Shape` class:

```
class Shape {

// ...

    virtual bool CollidesWith()=0;
};
```

And implement it in each one of your subclasses:

```
bool Sphere::CollidesWith()
{
   // ...
}

bool Capsule::CollidesWith()
{
   // ...
}
```

Now, have each one of these invoke one of those others `CollidesWith()` methods in that other class you mentioned in your question, simply passing `this`.

If you feel like it, you can implement another overload:

```
bool CollidesWith(Shape *s)
{
      return s->CollidesWith();
}
```

Your virtual method can take any other parameters you need, and forward them, if necessary. For example, your virtual method can take that `myRay` parameter in your example, and each subclass simply calls `myRay`, exactly as in your example of your desired code.

Comment: This solution couples the definition of Shape with the class that defines CollidesWith (he didn't name, so let it be X). So it assumes that Shape knows about X, and that he's has the possibility of modifying Shape.

Comment: Yeah, This actually worked out! I guess I didn't think of putting the CollidesWith function inside the base class, and then overloading the CollidesWith function to take the Shape and just run the shape's collideswith function inside of it.  Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I am getting old fashioned or is there a `virtual` keyword missing for  `CollidesWith` in your first snippet ?